# Getting numbers from string line? PHP

Tags: php, string, numbers

I have a function:
Function returns numbers from string line.

```
function get_numerics ($str) {
    preg_match_all('/\d+/', $str, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

And I need to get numbers to an array in my php file.
How to do that?

```
$counter = $user_count[$sk]; //$user_count[$sk] gives me a string line
//$user_count[$sk] is "15,16,18,19,18,17" - And i need those numbers seperated to an array
$skarray[] = get_numerics($counter); //Something is wrong?
```

Explode could work, but $user_count[$sk] line could be "15, 16, 19, 14,16"; ie it may or may not contain spaces.

Comment: What, exactly, is in that line?

Comment: please add more detail to your question provide an example or scneraio

Comment: Edited with meaning of the line

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: `$user_count[$sk]` array separated by space OR comma ?

Comment: @user2614879 see the update to my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17906120/212940) to cope with spaces if they are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex for this, [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) combined with [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) will do it:-

```
$user_count = "15 ,16,18 ,19,18, 17";
$numbers = explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $user_count));
var_dump($numbers);
```

Output:-

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string '15' (length=2)
  1 => string '16' (length=2)
  2 => string '18' (length=2)
  3 => string '19' (length=2)
  4 => string '18' (length=2)
  5 => string '17' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a string that looks like:

```
$str = "15,16,17,18,19";
```

And want to split them into an array, you can use **explode**

```
$arr = explode(",", $str);
```

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: .. i wonder how the **only** "answer" that does not solve OP problem have managed to get an upvote.

Comment: @tereško It is less rare than you might imagine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095569/how-to-increment-a-letter-n-times-per-iteration-and-store-in-an-array