# How to increment a letter N times per iteration and store in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, excel, loops, increment

```
$letter = array();
for ($i = 'A'; $i !== 'ZZ'; $i++){
        $letter[] .= $i;
}
print_r($letter);
```

From above script I do a loop from `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` ... `ZZ`.

Now, I want to make it as `A`, `C`, `E`, `G`, `I` ... `ZZ`. (**2** steps instead of **1**)

I need direction to do it.

Comment: *loop from A, B, C, D to ZZ* when `ZZ` will come.

Comment: I would say make an array of odd letters like 1 is A 3 is c etc..

Comment: try i++ twice instead of once

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate as the answer is not found on the page): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278603/php-range-from-a-to-zz and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003100/unexpected-behavior-with-strnatcmp-php

Comment: There is a lot of upvotes on Rahul's answer but it seems that no one bothered to test the method first.  It breaks.

Comment: @mickmackusa : For your information. OP doesn't mentioned he wants range as dynamic. That's why Sahil upvoted me. And when I answered, then OP specified that he wanted range as dynamic. That's correction for your blame. Thank you!

Comment: @RahulMeshram Your methods break.  Scroll all the way down to the bottom of your output array in your demo.  Notice that `Z_` never happens.  You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ord()` will not work because your end string is two characters long.

> Returns the ASCII value of the **first character of string**.

[Watch it break](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/87465295b663c0948d4d0c6355c88ed2c4a8465b).

From my testing, you need to check that the `end` string doesn't get "stepped over".  The perl-style character incrementation is a cool method, but it is a single-stepping method.  For this reason, an inner loop helps it along when necessary.  This is actually not a bother, in fact, it is useful because we need to check if the loop(s) should be broken on each single step.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c215837ebda413f60446b54f4e7094554d02e45))

```
function excelCols($letter,$end,$step=1){  // function doesn't check that $end is "later" than $letter
    if($step==0)return [];  // prevent infinite loop
    do{
        $letters[]=$letter;  // store letter
        for($x=0; $x<$step; ++$x){  // increment in accordance with $step declaration
            if($letter===$end)break(2);  // break if end is "stepped on"
            ++$letter;
        }
    }while(true);
    return $letters;    
}
echo implode(' ',excelCols('A','JJ',4));
echo "\n --- \n";
echo implode(' ',excelCols('A','BB',3));
echo "\n --- \n";
echo implode(' ',excelCols('A','ZZ',1));
echo "\n --- \n";
echo implode(' ',excelCols('A','ZZ',3));
```

Output:

```
A E I M Q U Y AC AG AK AO AS AW BA BE BI BM BQ BU BY CC CG CK CO CS CW DA DE DI DM DQ DU DY EC EG EK EO ES EW FA FE FI FM FQ FU FY GC GG GK GO GS GW HA HE HI HM HQ HU HY IC IG IK IO IS IW JA JE JI
 --- 
A D G J M P S V Y AB AE AH AK AN AQ AT AW AZ
 --- 
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z AA AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ AK AL AM AN AO AP AQ AR AS AT AU AV AW AX AY AZ BA BB BC BD BE BF BG BH BI BJ BK BL BM BN BO BP BQ BR BS BT BU BV BW BX BY BZ CA CB CC CD CE CF CG CH CI CJ CK CL CM CN CO CP CQ CR CS CT CU CV CW CX CY CZ DA DB DC DD DE DF DG DH DI DJ DK DL DM DN DO DP DQ DR DS DT DU DV DW DX DY DZ EA EB EC ED EE EF EG EH EI EJ EK EL EM EN EO EP EQ ER ES ET EU EV EW EX EY EZ FA FB FC FD FE FF FG FH FI FJ FK FL FM FN FO FP FQ FR FS FT FU FV FW FX FY FZ GA GB GC GD GE GF GG GH GI GJ GK GL GM GN GO GP GQ GR GS GT GU GV GW GX GY GZ HA HB HC HD HE HF HG HH HI HJ HK HL HM HN HO HP HQ HR HS HT HU HV HW HX HY HZ IA IB IC ID IE IF IG IH II IJ IK IL IM IN IO IP IQ IR IS IT IU IV IW IX IY IZ JA JB JC JD JE JF JG JH JI JJ JK JL JM JN JO JP JQ JR JS JT JU JV JW JX JY JZ KA KB KC KD KE KF KG KH KI KJ KK KL KM KN KO KP KQ KR KS KT KU KV KW KX KY KZ LA LB LC LD LE LF LG LH LI LJ LK LL LM LN LO LP LQ LR LS LT LU LV LW LX LY LZ MA MB MC MD ME MF MG MH MI MJ MK ML MM MN MO MP MQ MR MS MT MU MV MW MX MY MZ NA NB NC ND NE NF NG NH NI NJ NK NL NM NN NO NP NQ NR NS NT NU NV NW NX NY NZ OA OB OC OD OE OF OG OH OI OJ OK OL OM ON OO OP OQ OR OS OT OU OV OW OX OY OZ PA PB PC PD PE PF PG PH PI PJ PK PL PM PN PO PP PQ PR PS PT PU PV PW PX PY PZ QA QB QC QD QE QF QG QH QI QJ QK QL QM QN QO QP QQ QR QS QT QU QV QW QX QY QZ RA RB RC RD RE RF RG RH RI RJ RK RL RM RN RO RP RQ RR RS RT RU RV RW RX RY RZ SA SB SC SD SE SF SG SH SI SJ SK SL SM SN SO SP SQ SR SS ST SU SV SW SX SY SZ TA TB TC TD TE TF TG TH TI TJ TK TL TM TN TO TP TQ TR TS TT TU TV TW TX TY TZ UA UB UC UD UE UF UG UH UI UJ UK UL UM UN UO UP UQ UR US UT UU UV UW UX UY UZ VA VB VC VD VE VF VG VH VI VJ VK VL VM VN VO VP VQ VR VS VT VU VV VW VX VY VZ WA WB WC WD WE WF WG WH WI WJ WK WL WM WN WO WP WQ WR WS WT WU WV WW WX WY WZ XA XB XC XD XE XF XG XH XI XJ XK XL XM XN XO XP XQ XR XS XT XU XV XW XX XY XZ YA YB YC YD YE YF YG YH YI YJ YK YL YM YN YO YP YQ YR YS YT YU YV YW YX YY YZ ZA ZB ZC ZD ZE ZF ZG ZH ZI ZJ ZK ZL ZM ZN ZO ZP ZQ ZR ZS ZT ZU ZV ZW ZX ZY ZZ
 --- 
A D G J M P S V Y AB AE AH AK AN AQ AT AW AZ BC BF BI BL BO BR BU BX CA CD CG CJ CM CP CS CV CY DB DE DH DK DN DQ DT DW DZ EC EF EI EL EO ER EU EX FA FD FG FJ FM FP FS FV FY GB GE GH GK GN GQ GT GW GZ HC HF HI HL HO HR HU HX IA ID IG IJ IM IP IS IV IY JB JE JH JK JN JQ JT JW JZ KC KF KI KL KO KR KU KX LA LD LG LJ LM LP LS LV LY MB ME MH MK MN MQ MT MW MZ NC NF NI NL NO NR NU NX OA OD OG OJ OM OP OS OV OY PB PE PH PK PN PQ PT PW PZ QC QF QI QL QO QR QU QX RA RD RG RJ RM RP RS RV RY SB SE SH SK SN SQ ST SW SZ TC TF TI TL TO TR TU TX UA UD UG UJ UM UP US UV UY VB VE VH VK VN VQ VT VW VZ WC WF WI WL WO WR WU WX XA XD XG XJ XM XP XS XV XY YB YE YH YK YN YQ YT YW YZ ZC ZF ZI ZL ZO ZR ZU ZX
```

---

Here is an array-functions approach:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f83fbb9eee198182318cde7915a99a855c6909e))

```
$start='C';
$end='DD';
$step=4;

// generate and store more than we need (this is an obvious method disadvantage)
$result=$array=range('A','Z',1);  // store A - Z as $array and $result
foreach($array as $a){
    foreach($array as $b){
        $result[]="$a$b";  // store double letter combinations
        if(in_array($end,$result)){break(2);}  // stop asap
    }
}
//echo implode(' ',$result),"\n\n";

// slice away from the front of the array
$result=array_slice($result,array_search($start,$result));  // reindex keys
//echo implode(' ',$result),"\n\n";

 // punch out elements that are not "stepped on"
$result=array_filter($result,function($k)use($step){return $k%$step==0;},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY); // use modulo

// result is ready
echo implode(' ',$result);
```

Output:

```
C G K O S W AA AE AI AM AQ AU AY BC BG BK BO BS BW CA CE CI CM CQ CU CY DC
```

Comment: Wow it's very helpful code. FYI it requires at least PHP 5.4

Answer (score 3):

Here is your solution for the problem,

```
$letter = array();
for ($i = 'A'; $i !== 'ZZ'; $i++){
        if(ord($i) % 2 != 0)
           $letter[] .= $i;
}
print_r($letter);
```

You need to get the ASCII value for that character which will solve your problem.

Here is [ord](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) doc and working [code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4a7feebe74b3c4c91fa951c70d066da38ba329e0).

For your requirement, you can do like this,

```
for ($i = 'A'; $i !== 'ZZ'; ord($i)+$x){
  $letter[] .= $i;
}
print_r($letter);
```

Here set $x as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks but it only works A, C, E.. Can we make it as dynamic as possible? Such a 3 steps, 5 steps, x steps? Thanks

Comment: Your working code is not working.  ord() cannot be used the way you are using it.