# How to increment the letter of alphabet by 2 or more instead of 1 each time?

Tags: php, counter

I want to increment a letter by 2 each time, e.g.

```
// increment by 1
$alphabet = "A";
$alphabet++; // 'B'
```

I want something like

```
// increment by 2
$alphabet = "A";
$alphabet+=2; // 'C'
```

How can i do this? I tried the code above but encounter non numeric value.

Comment: There is no magic "addition" of characters, just multiple-increments.... if you want that, then create a `function incrementor(&$characters, $counter) { do $characters++; } while($counter-- > 0); }`, calling it like `incrementor($alphabet, 2);`

Comment: @MarkBaker Do you mean, i need to increment two times and there's no other better way to do this?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean

Comment: `$alphabet = chr(ord($alphabet)+2);`

Comment: @splash - works until $alphabet is `Y` or `Z`, then it gets rather different to the functionality that `++` would give

Comment: @MarkBaker, I hope, OP will not go so far :)

Comment: @splash58 If it's wanted for Excel spreadsheets, then it could go as high as IV or even XFD for the latest versions of MS Excel

Comment: @Mark XFD? What version is that? How many lines can it handle? Every single day I have to stitch together spreadsheets because I go above one million lines.

Comment: @Andreas That is a column limit (16,384 columns), 1,048,576 rows is the row limit for Excel2007 and above

Comment: @Mark ok. I thought it was something new. It would be great if they make it possible to swap columns for lines. I usually only need 200-300.000 more lines.

Comment: Perhaps relevant to researchers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46095569/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php [`chr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) and php [`ord`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php)

```
$alphabet = "A";
$ascii = ord($alphabet);
$ascii += 2;
echo $alphabet = chr($ascii);
```

LIve demo : https://eval.in/907132

Answer (score 2):

You can have an array with the alphabet created by range.
The just echo the one you need with a counter.

```
$alphabet = range("A", "Z");
$i =0;

Echo $alphabet[$i];
$i =($i+25)%26;
Echo $alphabet[$i];
```

https://3v4l.org/U49OY

Edit Mark has a good point in comments above.
Added a mod calculation to keep it between A-Z.

In the code it's the ($i+**25**)%26; that is the increment value.